# Build failure after adding AdView to layout

Tags: android, admob

I was following this guide at https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start and https://developers.google.com/admob/android/banner on how to set up an AdView in my layout but
I'm getting the following error after building

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':base:processDebugFeatureResources'.

  > Android resource linking failed
  >   Output:  D:\testproject\base\build\intermediates\merged_manifests\debugFeature\processDebugFeatureManifest\merged\AndroidManifest.xml:63: error: resource integer/google_play_services_version (aka test.dev.com.example.app:integer/google_play_services_version) not found.
  >   error: failed processing manifest.

Comment: make sure that u r google play services in sdk are installed. If  that is not an issue refer this https://www.androidhive.info/2016/02/android-how-to-integrate-google-admob-in-your-app/

Comment: Thanks for the response. I do have Google play services install but it says version 49 while under dependencies I had "implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.1.1'" Would this matter?

Comment: Once check with this compile ‘com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.8.0 in build.gradle

Comment: Still getting the same error after adding that to my gradle

Comment: Nevermind I found what the issue is. My project had a base package that uses the services. I had to add it to that manifest file instead of my app's manifest. Thanks for the help Varma